# An error occurs while compiling an idl file to an rdb file

Tags: sdk, libreoffice-calc, uno

Good afternoon.
I have an idl file, here is its contents:

```
#include <com/sun/star/uno/XInterface.idl>

module org { module libreoffice { module sheet { module formulas {

interface XDataLinkFormulas : com::sun::star::uno::XInterface {
    long Vol(
        [in] long a,
        [in] long b,
        [in] long c
    );
};

}; }; }; };
```

On Linux, I compile these files into an rdb file using the following command:

```
sudo ./unoidl-write formulas.idl formulas.rdb
```

However, this command fails with the following error:

> Bad input file:///opt/libreoffice7.5/sdk/bin/formulas.idl: cannot parse line 4: "interface type org.libreoffice.sheet.formulas.XDataLinkFormulas direct base com.sun.star.uno.XInterface does not resolve to an existing interface type"

[image]

**Question:** how do I fix this error, because I did the contents of the idl file by analogy with the existing examples.

P.S. I placed my idl (formulas.idl) file in the following directory (/opt/libreoffice7.5/sdk/bin)

Comment: I tried the new way but couldn't get it to work, so I went back to `idlc` and `regmerge`, which is still compatible with the latest version and also all previous versions, unlike `unoidl` which requires 4.1 or newer (admittedly, probably no one uses anything that old anymore). The example I found was `unoidl-write $unoTypes $offTypes com/sun/star/test/XSomethingA.idl XSomething.rdb` in case that helps. Anyway, if you get it working, please post an answer explaining how to do it.

Comment: And where can you download idlc and regmerge, because there are no programs in the LibreOffice\sdk\bin folders?

Comment: They're in [LibreOffice 7.4 or earlier](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/7.5#Feature_Removal_/_Deprecation). Look for `/sdk/bin/idlc` in the SDK and `/URE/bin/regmerge` in the core app. Even though the tools themselves aren't in 7.5, files generated by the tools will still work in 7.5.

Comment: Is there a working example of the idlc command?

Comment: Never mind the earlier comments — I got `unoidl` to work in 7.5 as explained in my answer. In case you want to see my `idlc` notes, they are in the answer's edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the interface type error, add a reference to `types.rdb`. Here is a working powershell script for Windows.

```bash
$idlFile = "../idl/XCalcFunctions"
$loHome = "C:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program"
$sdkHome = "C:/libreoffice7.5.3.2/sdk"
$tools = "$sdkHome/bin"
$unoTypes = "$loHome/types.rdb"
$offTypes = "$loHome/types/offapi.rdb"
$env:PATH += ';' + $loHome  # for DLLs

& "$tools/unoidl-write.exe" $unoTypes $offTypes "$idlFile.idl" "$idlFile.rdb"
```

This is based on the example at https://www.spinics.net/lists/libreoffice/msg09080.html.

```bash
export PATH=/usr/lib64/libreoffice/sdk/bin:/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program:/usr/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program:/usr/bin
export unoTypes=/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/types.rdb
export offTypes=/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/types/offapi.rdb
unoidl-write $unoTypes $offTypes com/sun/star/test/XSomethingA.idl XSomething.rdb
```

Comment: Thank you. On Linux, we managed to get the .rdb file.